# Javascript revealing Module, return private field

Tags: javascript

I'm quite confused by the revealing module pattern, when return a "private field" to outside world.
Here is the code,

```
    var vm2 = (function(){
    var 
        name = 'sean',
        changename = function(v){
            this.name=v;
        };

    return {
        name: name,
        foo: name,
        changename:changename
    };
}());

vm2.changename('jasper');
console.log(vm2.name);
console.log(vm2.foo);
```

I was confused by the result,  that vm2.name is 'jasper' while vm2.foo is still 'sean',
can someone help me understand it?

Comment: Can you explain why it is you think that "foo" would change?

Comment: @Pointy yes, I got fooled by "this", the "name" foo point to is not the "name" changename changed, your answer is correct, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "changename" function only updates the "name" property of the object; it doesn't mess with the local variable called "name" that's present in the closure, and it doesn't mess with "foo". Thus the "foo" property of the object retains it's initial value no matter what you pass to "changename".

So step by step:

1. The variable "vm2" is initialized by that anonymous function. It's value is an object with three properties.
2. The call to the "changename" function is made via the property reference on "vm2". That will cause `this` to be bound to that object while "changename" executes.
3. Inside "changename", the "name" property of the object referenced by `this` (which is the "vm2" object) is updated to whatever value is passed as the parameter.

Note that once "vm2" is initialized, nothing in that code touches "foo".

Comment: excellent answer! you are right, I was fooled by "this", when changename called, this.name is not the "private name", so change it will directly change the name property of vm2.

Answer (score 0):

How about this case? why the person is still the private one?

```
var vm = (function () {
        var person = { name: "jasper" };
        var changename = function (v) {
            //person.name = v;
            person = { };
        };

        return {
            person: person,
            changename: changename
        };
    })();

    vm.changename("sean");
    alert(vm.person.name);
```